# CSS rotation with respect to a reference point

Tags: css, rotation

How to rotate an element with respect to a defined point i.e. defined `x` & `y` coordinate in **CSS** (webkit)?

Normally rotation make element's center point as reference.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You could use transform-origin.
It defines the point to rotate around from the upper left corner of the element.

```
transform-origin: 0% 0%
```

This would rotate around the upper left corner.

For other options look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

for the safer side if this link not available then here are a couple of more options

```
transform-origin: center; // one of the keywords left, center, right, top, and bottom

transform-origin: top left; // same way can use two keywords

transform-origin: 50px 50px; // specific x-offset | y-offset

transform-origin: bottom right 60px; // third part is for 3D transform : z-offset
```

As far as I know there isn't an option to rotate around a fixed point (although this would be handy).

Comment: That's awesome, I had no idea this was put into effect yet :)

Comment: For webkit based browser you maybe need the prefix: `-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%`

Comment: @kufi That's a great solution. a link is broken replace with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Answer (score 1):

If you need a specific offset, one way is to edit your image to make it larger, such that the centre lies in the middle of your image. You can then place this within a DIV with "overflow: none" and position it with relative positioning. The div will mask off the area of the image you don't wish to display.

Answer (score 0):

**It is now August 2022**, older answers do not include the use of px as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin).

transform-origin accepts keyboards (left, right, top, bottom, or center), percentage (50%, 69%...) or length describing how far from the left edge of the box the origin of the transform is set.

Therefore `transform-origin: 360px 540px;` is absolutely fine and works as expected.