# Rotate Svg element clockwise

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

```html
<svg>
       <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#012d26" d=" M 81.16 38.23 C 83.16 42.68 85.01 47.20 87.05 51.63 C 89.59 57.31 91.99 63.04 94.50 68.73 C 107.87 65.61 122.71 76.15 123.25 90.07 C 124.68 103.15 112.95 115.43 99.93 115.20 C 87.82 115.97 76.31 106.03 75.34 93.93 C 74.34 84.23 80.19 74.37 89.14 70.51 C 87.75 64.47 86.08 58.49 84.69 52.45 C 83.60 47.69 82.33 42.97 81.16 38.23 Z"/>
    </svg>
```

I want to rotate this in clockwise direction like clock. BUt using transform:rotate(10deg) will shift its base points. I want to keep the points fixed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633536/css-rotation-with-respect-to-a-reference-point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `transform` & `transform-origin` like so:

```css
svg path {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg);

  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
      -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%; 
          transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4st5tn6o/)

Comment: Thanks ... `transform-origin: 50% 70%;` adding this solved the problem !

Comment: @atulquest93 If this answers your question, then please mark as solved.